# Get Minimum value of Each Query in Filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two tables 1 product and 2nd price.like this

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    activityName = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=False, blank=False)
    activityId = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)


class PerPersonTire(models.Model):
     activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name= models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True , blank=True)
     minNumerofParticipents = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     price=models.IntegerField(default=0)



 class groupTire(models.Model):
     activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name= models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True , blank=True)
     minNumerofParticipents = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     price=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now case is in every activity have many price in foreign key. So when I Query on Activity I need minimum price from that table aswell.

like

```
Activity.object.all()
```

I need here minimum price of each activity from price table as well. Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Activity Now Can either have a group price or single price . So how I can calculate both type price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do it using `annotate` something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Min

activities = Activity.object.all().annotate(
    min_person_price=Min('perpersontire__price'),
    min_group_price=Min('grouptire__price'),
)

for activity in activities:
    print(
        activity.activityName, 
        activity.min_person_price, 
        acitivy.min_group_price,
    )
```

---

You might want to read the Django's official documentation on [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/). They have multiple such examples.

Comment: Dipen I have a problem , I actually have 2  tables for price .

Comment: Please can you add the other table in the description?

Comment: Model and description added . Product price can be either group or person . So From this method I am able to calculate perpersontire__price  but not 2nd one

Comment: is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, possible. I have updated the answer. Please check!

Comment: thanks bro <3 . Is there any resource from where I can learn these type of queries etc ?

Comment: Django's official documentation is quite good. Most of the time, you will get an answer from there. Otherwise Google search :)